# Как работают срезы в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice

Как работает синтаксис срезов в Python? То есть, когда я пишу код вроде

```py
a[x:y:z], a[:], a[::2]
```

и т. д., как мне понять, какие элементы попадают в срез?

**P.S.** Это перевод [вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/how-slicing-in-python-works) c enSO.

<sub><sup>Интересующихся темой "зачем делать такие переводы" прошу [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/translate-from-english)</sup></sub>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот синтаксис срезов:

```py
a[start:stop]  # от start до stop
a[start:]      # от start до конца последовательности
a[:stop]       # от начала последовательности до stop
a[:]           # копирует последовательность целиком
```

Есть также значение "шаг", его можно использовать в сочетании с любым из примеров выше.

```
a[start:stop:step] # от start до stop с шагом step
```

Следует помнить, что значение `:stop` представляет первое значение, которого нет в выбранном срезе. Поэтому разница между `stop` и `start` — это количество выбранных элементов (Если `step` — 1, по умолчанию).

Есть еще одна особенность: `start` и `stop` могут быть отрицательными. Это значит, что считать нужно с конца контейнера, а не с начала.

```
a[-1]    # последний элемент последовательности
a[-2:]   # два последних элемента последовательности
a[:-2]   # все, кроме двух последних элементов
```

Аналогично, `step` тоже может быть отрицательным:

```
a[::-1]    # все элементы контейнера, но в обратном порядке
a[1::-1]   # первые два элемента в обратном порядке
a[:-3:-1]  # последние два элемента в обратном порядке
a[-3::-1]  # все, кроме последних двух элементов, в обратном порядке
```

Python дружественен к программисту, если в последовательности меньше элементов, чем вы просите. Например, если вы пишете `a[:-2]`, а в `a` только один элемент, вместо ошибки вы получите пустой список. Иногда в этом случае бывает нужна ошибка, поэтому будьте осторожны.

### Связь с объектом `slice`

Объект `slice` может представлять оператор среза, т.е.:

```
a[start:stop:step]
```

эквивалентно:

```
a[slice(start, stop, step)]
```

Объекты `slice` также ведут себя немного по-разному в зависимости от количества аргументов, как функция `range()`, т.е. будет правильным и `slice(stop)`, и `slice(start, stop[, step])`. Чтобы пропустить какой-либо аргумент, вставьте вместо него `None`. То есть, например, `a[start:]` эквивалентно `a[slice(start, None)]`, а `a[::-1]` — то же, что `a[slice(None, None, -1)]`.

В то время, как синтаксис с ":" очень полезен для простых операций со срезами, явное использование объекта `slice()` упрощает программную генерацию срезов.

*Примечание переводчика. Я использую слово "последовательность", а не "список" вместо оригинального array, потому что срезы относятся не только к спискам, но и к кортежам, и прочим подобным последовательностям.*

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, не понял, к чему вы это?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, а, понял, действительно, переклинило меня что-то. Естественно, множества не поддерживают порядок элементов, сейчас поправлю.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, вы правы, хотя я слышал, что употребляется и слово "контейнер". Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: Мне кажется, подобные самоответы полезны для нетривиальных вещей - но ведь это вот всё неплохо описано в справке

Comment: @MBo, на enSO вопрос входит в величайшие из величайших хитов. Впрочем, в следующий раз постараюсь перевести что-нибудь поинтереснее.

Comment: А вот вам самому интересно было ответ читать, много нового из ответа узнали? Это не подкол, просто недоумеваю (может, и зря)

Comment: @MBo, в основном ничего, только про объект slice не знал.