# Как удалить часть из одной переменной (не из списка) в Python

Tags: python, html, переменные

У меня есть переменная в которой уже есть строка из кода одного сайта, мне нужно получить промокод из этой строки. То-есть я должен каким-то образом удалить часть до промокода и после. Как это сделать?

Сама переменная (при выводе в консоль):

```html
<div data-title="Скопировать промокод" data-toggle="tooltip" id="promocodeBox" onclick="copy('2mRCAg2s9IClqJ8', 'Промокод скопирован')">
        2mRCA<span>-</span>g2s9I<span>-</span>ClqJ8
</div>
```

Comment: Срез. Простой и элементарный. Насколько я понимаю, количество символов до промокода(ов) одинаково, так что просто срезайте строку и все. Если количество символов переменно — пользуйтесь регуляркой (например, ориентируйтесь на треугольные скобки).

Comment: Глеб, я вот и спрашивал как это сделать, в интернете просто я не нашёл.

Comment: Не знаешь, что такое срез? Тогда тебе не сайты парсить надо, а питон учить. Срез — это получение отрывка строки. Почитай [вот этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1546800/Как-работают-срезы-в-python) вопрос, переводил недавно. В интернете ты этого, конечно, не найдешь — яндекс тебя просто не поймет. Нужно просто подучить питон, и через две недели ты посмотришь на задачу другими глазами. Сам через это проходил, гарантирую.

Comment: @Глеб, Спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю использовать регулярное выражение для поиска промика:

```
import re

# Ваша переменная (при выводе в консоль):
html_string = """
<div data-title="Скопировать промокод" data-toggle="tooltip" id="promocodeBox" onclick="copy('2mRCAg2s9IClqJ8', 'Промокод скопирован')">
        2mRCA<span>-</span>g2s9I<span>-</span>ClqJ8
</div>
"""

# Тут запишем регулярное выражение для поиска промика
promo_code = re.search(r"copy\('([A-Za-z0-9]+)',", html_string)

if promo_code:
    #Тут мы хотим получить первую группу совпадений (выраженную круглыми скобками в регулярном выражении)
    promo_code = promo_code.group(1)
    print("Найден промокод:", promo_code)
else:
    print("Промокод не найден")
```

```
Консоль:
Найден промокод: 2mRCAg2s9IClqJ8
```